# How to validate assertion error in production code with ExpectedException in a JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, assert

Having an assertion somewhere in a method `myMethod` in the production code like:

```
public void myMethod(List list1, List list2) {
 assert list1.size() == list2.size()
}
```

and a unit test

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException ex = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
 ex.expect(java.lang.AssertionError.class);
 myMethod(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
}
```

I expect the unit test to successfully run but I get the `AssertionError`. Why is it so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know what the keyword does. I just wanted to know how can I use it in my unit test and the Rule for ExpectedException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using 4.11, the [javadoc of `ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) states

> By default `ExpectedException` rule doesn't handle `AssertionErrors` and
>   `AssumptionViolatedExceptions`, because such exceptions are used by
>   JUnit. If you want to handle such exceptions you have to call
>   `handleAssertionErrors()` or `handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions()`.

Assuming assertions are enabled with the `-ea` option, just add the call the `handleAssertionErrors()`

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ex.handleAssertionErrors();
    ex.expect(java.lang.AssertionError.class);
    myMethod(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
}
```

---

[You should no longer need the above in JUnit 4.12 (or in versions 10 and under).](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#handleAssertionErrors())

> Deprecated. AssertionErrors are handled by default since JUnit 4.12. Just like in JUnit <= 4.10.
>
> This method does nothing. Don't use it.